# Вопрос касается постановки тире, но в большей степени отсутствия запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Предложение: "То же самое он сделал бы и сейчас - но разве можно было остановиться именно в этот момент, когда вычисления сулили столь блестящие результаты!"

С тире я, похоже, для себя разобралась. https://therules.ru/?q=%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5 - здесь, в пункте 169, нашла ответ, хотя все еще не очень уверена.

Меня больше волнует отсутствие запятой перед союзом ***но*.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*То же самое он сделал бы и сейчас – **но разве** можно было остановиться именно в этот момент, когда вычисления сулили столь блестящие результаты!*

1. Я предпочитаю пользоваться **официальным справочником Розенталя**, а не учебными сайтами. Их можно использовать в качестве дополнительного материала, но вряд ли ссылка на любой сайт будет авторитетной (таких ресурсов множество с Сети).
   § 32. Тире в сложносочиненном предложении http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135
2. Тире считается **неосновным знаком** в сложносочиненном предложении, оно может **заменять** запятую, обозначая увеличенную паузу, но для этого нужны основания.

Розенталь называет **три темы**, но  что подходит сюда – вот в чем вопрос. Неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление, назывные предложения, две смысловые части?

3. Вроде бы ничего такого, мысли связанные, ничего неожиданного нет, а смысловые отношения вполне выражены противительным союзом НО, тогда ставится **только запятая**.
4. Может быть, **разная структура**? Да, пожалуй. Вторая часть – это риторический вопрос, особый оборот речи, художественное средство выразительности. К тому же распространенный. Достаточные основания для постановки тире вместо запятой.
5. Но, может быть, поставить **единый знак** (запятую и тире)? Но он выражает значительно увеличенную паузу, а здесь этого не нужно.  Одно тире, заменяющее запятую, вполне подходит.